# union of two tables from two different databases of mysql

Tags: mysql, database, union

hello i am doing union operation on two tables which are in two different databases but i am getting empty set

i don't know what i am doing wrong my query is below pls point me what am i missing

```
(SELECT *
      , 'ta' as attendence 
   from attendence.users 
  where company_name = 'MCC-INDIA' 
    and company_name = 'Ceekay Logistics Private Limited.'
 ) 
 UNION ALL 
 (SELECT *
       , 'ka' as kaina_php 
    from kaina_test.users 
   where company_name = 'MCC-INDIA' 
     and company_name = 'Ceekay Logistics Private Limited.'
  );
```

Comment: that means that none off the records does match the WHERE clause in both selects..

Comment: For what you're missing, see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: hello @RaymondNijland there is data but when i reduce one company_name from where clause then i am getting data. i dont know what is wrong may u can point out

Comment: *"there is data but when i reduce one company_name from where clause then i am getting data. i dont know what is wrong may u can point out"* without example data which @Strawberry already suggested.. i am not going to try as SQL is a declarative language where you define what you want and not how to get it..

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this

```
-- FROM DB1
 SELECT *
 FROM [MyDatabaseOnDB1].[dbo].[MyTable] tab1
 INNER JOIN [DB2].[MyDatabaseOnDB2].[dbo].[MyOtherTable] tab2
    ON tab1.ID = tab2.ID
```

Or

```
-- Fetch data from the other database server
 SELECT *
 INTO #myTempTable
FROM OPENQUERY([DB2], 'SELECT * FROM [MyDatabaseOnDB2].[dbo].[MyOtherTable]')

-- Now I can join my temp table to see the data
SELECT * FROM [MyDatabaseOnDB1].[dbo].[MyTable] tab1
INNER JOIN #myTempTable tab2 ON tab1.ID = tab2.ID
```